# RDFLib: Namespace prefixes in XML serialization

Tags: python, namespaces, rdflib

In a Python script using [RDFLib 3.0](http://www.rdflib.net/), I get the following XML-Output when serializing my triples:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:_3="http://www.my-example.intra/ontologies/ci.owl#"
>
```

How can I define specific namespace prefixes for those anonymous _x-prefixes automatically assigned by RDFLib (or it's XML-Serializer respectively)?

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:ex="http://www.my-example.intra/ontologies/ci.owl#"
>
```

Many thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to this by looking at some (quite messily distributed) rdflib doc files. For the (Conjunctive)Graph storing the triples, call

```
mygraph.bind(prefix, URIRef(url))
```

i.e.

```
mygraph.bind('ex', URIRef('http://www.my-example.intra/ontologies/ci.owl#'))
```

Passing 'False' as 3rd argument overrides existing namespace prefix bindings.